# Download big number of files (400k) from S3 bucket into Azure Datalake Gen2 using Azure Data Factory

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to download a big number of files (around 400k) files from an S3 bucket. I have the paths stored in a csv file. Some of the paths may not exist.

The two options i see are:

1. Use the `foreach` activity and somehow pass the contents of the file there. But i think that this would flood my monitor pane with a huge number of runs, and it feels like it is meant to be for smaller pipelines.
2. Use the listOfFiles option which is supported in the S3 source. The problem with this approach is that the list *must be in the S3 bucket* and cannot be loaded from Azure Datalake Gen2 (anybody knows why, please let me know as well).

I have tried using the `listOfFiles` way, but the pipeline fails once it finds the first missing file. The fault tolerance options contain a "skip missing file" option but it is defined as "Skip the files if it is being deleted from source store during the data movement", so it is of no use to me.

I don't want to download more files than needed, so copying the bucket as-is is not an option. How can i approach this issue with ADF? I'm looking for a solution that uses the predefined transformations, ideally i would like to not involve Azure Batch or Azure Functions for such a simple task.

Comment: Can you use PySpark for this?

Comment: Yeah - but I would expect that this is not such a complex scenario that cannot be expressed in ADF only.